# SQL Developer help missing comma error

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am creating a table in Oracle.

On doing the following insert I keep getting missing comma error but no comma is missing from what I can see

```
INSERT INTO driver 
  (employee_no, first_name, last_name, ni_no, telephone, hazardous_goods)
VALUES 
  (122085,'Norris','Vasyutichev','EE 91 44 59 G',01809 7872896,07610 2265827,'Y');
```

even with

```
INSERT INTO driver 
  (first_name, last_name, ni_no, hazardous_goods)
VALUES
  ('Norris','Vasyutichev','EE914459G','Y');
```

I get the missing comma error

> *Error at Command Line:27 Column:86
>
>   Error report:
>
>   SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
>
>   00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed actually by putting space between the number `"01809 7872896"` and it should be `"018097872896"` without space and this one `"07610 2265827"` to `"076102265827"`. If it's matched with the column list. If not, change it to string by putting single quotes around them. Like `'01809 7872896,07610 2265827'` and I think you should do the second one as it seems to be phone numbers separated by a comma as a string.

Cheers

Comment: tried getting rid of the space, and puting single quotes around them still got the error :(

Comment: Sir you should do the second way I said. By the way please share the exact error text with me. I'm waiting.

Comment: i tried the second one first and it didn't work, then i tried to get rid of the spaces without quotes, that also didn't work, so tried it with quotes and without spaces and that didnt work either, i have added a bit extra to my problem on the original post

Comment: You have 27 lines of code?! Are you sure the 27th line refers to this insert statement?

Comment: i have 56 lines of code, using date from excel with the insert statement

line 27 is:
INSERT INTO driver (first_name, last_name, ni_no, hazardous_goods) VALUES('Eamon','O'Looney','JJ565326B','N'); the same as the examples i used

Comment: I think I just saw the problem man! change "'O'Looney'" to "'O''Looney'"! You ended the string with the single quote after "O". The single quote afte the letter O is your problem. You should put two single quotes to ignore one. Yeah?

Comment: My mates always say that my eyes act like a parser! I parse the code as I read it the first time... :D Happy to hear your problem solved. Cheers bro...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO driver 
  (employee_no, first_name, last_name, ni_no, telephone, hazardous_goods)
VALUES 
  (122085,'Norris','Vasyutichev','EE 91 44 59 G','01809 7872896, 07610 2265827','Y');
```

Also, it looks like you are trying to store multiple phone numbers using a comma as a delimiter. You should try to avoid that and instead create a new table called employeePhoneNumbers. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employeePhoneNumbers
( 
    employee_no    INT,
    telephone      VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Add a foreign key constraint on employee_no.

And then insert a new record for each phone number:

```
INSERT INTO employeePhoneNumbers(employee_no, telephone) VALUES (122085, '01809 7872896');
INSERT INTO employeePhoneNumbers(employee_no, telephone) VALUES (122085, '07610 2265827');
```

You may ask why to do this? For database normalization. Read more here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30646

Comment: Answerer put quotes around the phone number.  I suppose the space or extra comma in the data value was throwing off the parser.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, but I wasn't missing a comma on my insert statement, nor was I using double quotes, both of which will throw this error.

What I had left out was the closing parenthesis for the values of my insert statement, but Oracle SQL Developer gave me this error.

```
Error at Command Line:84 Column:40
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
```

The hint I got was that it was at the end of my statement, which clearly doesn't require a comma there.